# JpaRepository возвращает null

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data, vaadin

Пытаюсь подключить базу данных к своему vaadin проекту, используя javaConfig. Но при попытке получить все значения с любой из таблиц в бд - получаю null.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

База данных конечно же заполнена.
Интерфейс HotelService и его реализация:
HotelCategoryServiceImpl.java

```
package com.gptravel.service.category;


import com.gptravel.dao.HotelCategoryRepository;
import com.gptravel.entity.HotelCategory;
import com.gptravel.service.hotel.HotelServiceImpl;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Logger;    

@Service("hotelCategoryService")
@Transactional
public class HotelCategoryServiceImpl implements HotelCategoryService {
private static final Logger LOGGER = 
Logger.getLogger(HotelServiceImpl.class.getName());

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

@Autowired
private HotelCategoryRepository hotelCategoryRepo;

@Override
public HotelCategory create(HotelCategory hotelCategory) {
    HotelCategory savehotelCategory = 
 hotelCategoryRepo.saveAndFlush(hotelCategory);
    return savehotelCategory;
}

@Override
public void delete(long id) {
    hotelCategoryRepo.delete(id);

}

@Override
public HotelCategory getById(long id) {
    return hotelCategoryRepo.findOne(id);
}

@Override
public HotelCategory update(HotelCategory hotelCategory) {
    return hotelCategoryRepo.saveAndFlush(hotelCategory);
}

//get all categories
@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public  List<HotelCategory> findAll() {
    return hotelCategoryRepo.findAll();
}
}
```

HotelCategoryService.java

```
package com.gptravel.service.category;


import com.gptravel.entity.HotelCategory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service("hotelCategoryService")
public interface HotelCategoryService {

HotelCategory create(HotelCategory hotelCategory);
void delete(long id);
HotelCategory getById(long id);
HotelCategory update(HotelCategory hotelCategory);
List<HotelCategory> findAll();
}
```

Repository:

```
import com.gptravel.entity.HotelCategory;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface HotelCategoryRepository extends 
JpaRepository<HotelCategory, Long> {

List<HotelCategory> findAllBy(Pageable pageable);
}
```

Jpa Config.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("com.gptravel")
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="com.gptravel.dao")
public class HibernateConfig {

@Resource
private Environment environment;

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
    dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() throws NamingException {
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new 
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new 
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.gptravel.entity");
    factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());

    factoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass
    (HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
    factoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties());
    factoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("demo_hotels");
    factoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
    return factoryBean.getObject();
}

private Properties jpaProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", 
environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", 
environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", 
environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
    return properties;
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() throws 
NamingException {
    JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());
    return txManager;
}

@Bean
public SpringLiquibase liquibase() {
    SpringLiquibase liquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
    liquibase.setChangeLog("classpath:db/db.changelog.xml");
    liquibase.setDataSource(dataSource());
    return liquibase;
}
}
```

Есть простой тест в приложении по получению данных с бд - он завершается успешно.
TestJpaConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("com.gptravel")
public class TestDataBaseConfig {

private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo_hotels";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME = "demo";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD = "demo";

private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL = "true";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN = "com.gptravel.entity";
private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO = "update";

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistence.class);
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN);

    entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(hibernateProp());

    return entityManagerFactoryBean;
}

@Bean
public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());

    return transactionManager;
}

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

    dataSource.setDriverClassName(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER);
    dataSource.setUrl(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL);
    dataSource.setUsername(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME);
    dataSource.setPassword(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD);

    return dataSource;
}

private Properties hibernateProp() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT);
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL);
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO);
    return properties;
}

}
```

TestClass.java

```
@DirtiesContext
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestDataBaseConfig.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class HotelServiceImplTest {
@Resource
private EntityManagerFactory emf;
protected EntityManager em;

@Resource
private HotelRepository hotelCategoryService;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
em = emf.createEntityManager();
}

@Test
public void testSaveHotelCategory() throws Exception {
hotelCategoryService.findAll();
List<Hotel> testList = hotelCategoryService.findAll();
System.out.println("Size - " + testList.size());


}

}
```

В чем может быть проблема?

**UPDATE #1**

Ссылка на репозиторий: [VaadinJPAHotelApp](https://bitbucket.org/dmitriu_p/gptravel)

Comment: Если вам не затруднит, добавьте код, в котором вы считаете появляется ошибка, в текстовом виде.

Comment: Где именно ошибка, я понять не могу пока что